# Should exceptions contain dynamic data?

Tags: c#, java, php

I have such method:

```
public function someMethod($param1 = null, $param2 = null)
{
   ...
   if ($param1 == null &&...)
   {
        throw new Exception("Some parameter is wrong", 601);
    }
}
```

Is it a good practice to include dynamic data in the Exception msg, since I have the exception code ? For example the exception could look like this:

```
 throw new Exception("First parameter is wrong. You passed: {$param1}", 601);
```

What is your opinion, is it okey messages to be dynamic or I should stick to fixed text for the Exception messages ?

Comment: Throwing an Exception is never a good thing. You should create different custom exception class extending Exception. Depending on the issue you can throw different exception.

Comment: That is valid point. I am using custom exceptions I just simplified the example.

Comment: Simply tell that `param1` is wrong and why it's wrong, don't pass the value of the parameter, because can contain sensitive data.

Comment: How can it be sensitive data? The user just passed it in!

Answer (score 1):

> Should exceptions contain dynamic data?

Should? No. but they can! but be sure that "generating" this dynamic data will not cause another exception.

But you should never `throw new Exception()`. Extend it for your own custom exceptions or use javas exceptions like `IllegalArgumentException`